# Замена рабочего окружения XFCE на KDE Plasma

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop, kde, xfce

Хотел спросить совета, возможно я сильно туплю или не могу нормальный запрос в гугле сформировать.
Но в гугле стоящей инфы не нашёл.

У меня стоит **XUbuntu 20.04 LTS**, соответственно рабочее окружение **xfce**.
Хочу поставить **KDE Plasma**.

Из выходов пока вижу переустановку *XUbuntu* на *KUbuntu*.
Но я ведь в самом начале, после установки уебунты этой штрудировал книгу по администрированию линухи.
И там были рассказаны плюсы этих операционок, как изолированность рабочего окружения от ядра, и то, что я смогу сменить их.

Возможно есть выход, как не переустанавливая всю ось в целом попросту сменить *xfce* на *KDE*?

**UPD**: сделал по мануалам и по вашим комментариям (@alexandrbarakin @ильяилья) - после ребута, появилась плашка в выборе DE сверху справа - "Plasma".
После выбора красивенько подгружается и больше ничего. Чёрный экран, курсор и слева сверху появляется голубоватое свечение при наведении, при нажатии на которое показывается апплет "Notes" с записками.

**UPD1**: Смог всё таки через Alt+F2 запустить консоль. И даже сделать скриншот!)))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: установите kde-plasma-desktop (KDE Plasma Desktop and minimal set of applications) или kde-standard (KDE Plasma Desktop and standard set of applications) или вообще (это будет идентично вашему выбору замены xubuntu на kubuntu, только без переустановки) kubuntu-desktop (Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system). [полный список мета-пакетов для выпуска с кодовым название focal, цифрами: 20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/metapackages/allpackages?format=txt.gz)

Comment: Я так и устанавливал, ведь в гайдах именно это и прописано, но попробую установить kde-standard

Comment: ну а после установки любого из упомянутых выше пакетов надо переключить session-manager: `$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` и перезапустить свою x-сессию (логаут+логин).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin сейчас попытаюсь. Чуть что - апдейтну коммент.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ничего не произошло. После логаута заходил в ту же сессию xfce, в сессию xubuntu, в сессию с Plasma. В первом и втором случае - всё осталось также. В третьей как было, так и осталось - чёрный экран, курсор с рабочим поиском по Alt+F2, и синее свечение при наведении в левом верхнем углу экрана.

Comment: ну так всё работает. только финтифлюшек не хватает. поставьте следующий по списку (из моего первого комментария) пакет — финтифлюшек больше привалит. сессию, конечно, надо будет перезапустить. а для верности (не все демоны, запущенные de от имени пользователя, завершают работу после завершения x-сессии) перезагрузить компьютер.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin поставить в сессии xfce? Или через консоль в Plasma? Ибо я уже всё поставил в XFCE. И плазма-десктоп, и стандарт, и десктоп

Comment: ну и dm, наверно, стоит запускать другой. kdm он называется, или как-то в этом духе. вот первая попавшаяся инструкция, с картинками: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/change-default-display-manager-ubuntu-20-04/ // `поставить в сессии xfce` — устанавливать и удалять пакеты можно независимо от того, какая x-сессия у вас в данный момент запущена, и даже запущена ли вообще.

Comment: это вы перечисляете мета-пакеты, приведённые мной в первом комментарии? они отличаются только количеством зависимостей. я перечислил в порядке возрастания количества зависимостей.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 
// `kdm он называется`
Я видел, что советовали для кед ставить не kdm, а ssdm. Что из этого лучше запускать?
// `мета-пакеты` - а к чему тот список? Что с ним делать? Я пытался загуглить, но что с тем списком делать я так и не понял.

Изначально я подумал про те пакеты, которые вы перечисляли и описывали вкратце (_kde-plasma-desktop, kde-standard, kubuntu-desktop_). Я их, грубо говоря, поставил все. Ещё из какого-то гайда ставил что-то типа *kde-full* или *kubuntu-full*

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124039/discussion-between-leviathan-zc-and-aleksandr-barakin).

Answer (score 1):

Когда то делал подобное по мануалу https://losst.ru/ustanovka-kde-5-v-ubuntu-15-10

При перезагрузке во время входа в систему в углу должен был появиться значок переключения между средами. Такого не произошло. Попробую ещё раз и постараюсь отписаться, если всё не полетит.

UPD: Вспомнил, что во время установки на стадии выбора менеджера дисплеев у меня вроде как или выбора не было, или настройки не происходило, как в мануале.

А, и данный мануал скорее подходит для Ubuntu, у которой либо GNOME, либо Unity установлена в качестве графической оболочки.

Comment: Делал по этому мануалу. При перезагрузке во время входа в систему в углу должен был появиться значок переключения между средами. Такого не произошло. Попробую ещё раз и постараюсь отписаться, если всё не полетит)))
UPD: Вспомнил, что во время установки на стадии выбора менеджера дисплеев у меня вроде как или выбора не было, или настройки не происходило, как в мануале.

Comment: А, и данный мануал скорее подходит для Ubuntu, у которой либо GNOME, либо Unity установлена в качестве графической оболочки.

Comment: дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: почему мои комментарии к ответу добавились к самому ответу? Я так не делал вроде как....

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я не дополнял ответ. Это не мой ответ. Я просто прокомментировал, что тоже пытался делать по этому гайду.

Comment: вы можете отредактировать ответ, нажав [edit]. только прежде прочтите ещё раз мой первый комментарий, пожалуйста.